# What is VB6's native UI design pattern?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

We're rewriting an old VB6 app in .Net and WPF.  I'm going to be helping some co-workers who support the old app get up to speed in WPF and MVVM.    My background is in .Net and C# so I don't know VB6, but I'd like to understand where they're coming from.   What is VB6's native design pattern (assuming it has one)?     Looking at the code it looks like it might be MVC, but is that right?

Comment: Was the original program a desktop program or a web program (classic ASP)?

Comment: In that case, see my answer below. I'm less familiar with classic ASP but I've been working on VB6 desktop apps since VB6 came out 14 years ago...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses no design pattern. As a language, VB6 is a general one. The IDE and framework uses RAD approach, in procedural event driven style. The same thing applies to C#, except it uses object oriented event driven instead.

Comment: VB6 is not purely procedural. It does have objects, [interface inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242069(v=vs.60).aspx) and polymorphism, but it doesn't have implementation inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

Was the original program a desktop program or a web program (classic ASP)?

Frameworks:

- Desktop VB6 programs are similar to .Net WinForms. WPF is going to seem strange. MVVM is likely to be unfamiliar.
- Classic ASP. Fairly similar to PHP, but with a way to call up DLLs. So, like PHP, some people [developed organised frameworks](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01b.html) of their own, and others wrote spaghetti. [Can anyone improve on this part of my answer?]

Do your coworkers like reading? You could recommend

- Dan Appleman's excellent book for ex-VB6 programmers [Moving to VB .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059102X). Now ten years old, but still very insightful. It doesn't cover MVVM or WPF. It targets VB.Net rather than C#, but most of it is still relevant.
- [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Migration Resource Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788233.aspx) (an excellent resource)

Other things to bear in mind: VB6 is an *object-based* language (it has objects, polymorphism, and interface inheritance through [`Implements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242069(v=vs.60).aspx), but no implementation inheritance). It is event-based, like .Net. Object lifetimes are deterministic because it uses reference counting. There are no generics.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an attempt to explain MVVM using VB6 [here](http://ldloc.blogspot.com/2013/03/understanding-mvvm-at-basic-level.html).

One tip I will like to add is with VB6 migration projects it is always best to refactor/modify code before hand. Although VB6 to VB.net conversion wizard in visual studio does a good job but there are too many pain points. Avoiding them by modifying VB6 is lot easier than fixing the issues in VB.net.